# How can I catch Node.js startup errors using the Chrome-Node-Debugger?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, google-oauth, config, chrome-debugging

I have an error that occurs at startup when I create a new Google strategy.  This errror was introduced when I upgraded my config package.

I want to catch the error in the debugger, but the debugger will not connect unless Node starts up with out errors.

The error occurs here:

```
let credentials = helper.getPassport();
console.log(credentials) //   can see no difference but this is the fail point
let google_strategy = new GoogleStrategy(credentials, ()=>{}); // error
```

Comment: did you run node with --inspect flag?

Comment: Yes.  I have to manually remove and put back the application folder each time for some reason.

Comment: I don't follow so what i believe is you can use `--inspect-brk=127.0.0.1:9229` which is the default debugging port this command while starting node will just put a break before user code starts